# Which one is correct in the sentence, express or expressed?

Tags: word-usage

Is it the "express interest" of the manager o the "expressed interest" of the manager? Which one is the correct one?

Comment: I believe the answer you're looking for is *express interest*.. however, in certain contexts, "expressed interest" is perfectly valid..

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. They mean different things, and you have not provided us any context to help you determine which is correct, nor any evidence you have tried to look up the definitions of *express* or *expressed* in a dictionary. I encourage you to take the [site tour](http://english.stackexchange.com/tour) and review the [help center](http://english.stackexchange.com/help). Our sister site for [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com/) may also be of interest.

Comment: While this question is not particularly well written, this is not "off-topic", and should not have been closed as such.

Answer (score 3):

It depends on the context. An *[express interest](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/express)* is a

> 2. Particular; specific:

interest: The manager has an *express* interest in getting a large pay raise.

An *expressed interest* is one that has been stated or explained:-

> 1. a. To set forth in words; state: express an opinion.

so the manager has an *expressed* interest in whatever he said he was interested in (even if he was only pretending).

(the Free Dictionary).